# How to derive the energy of solvation equation?

Tags: energy, solutions

The work done as a ion is solvated is given by: $-z^2e^2/8\pi\epsilon r$ but since the top line can be written $Q^2$, for simplicity I will say the equation is $-Q^2/8\pi\epsilon r$. Is this derived from integrating potential with respect to charge $Q$?

i.e    $$w=\int_Q^0 VdQ$$ where $$V=Q/4 \pi \epsilon r$$

I believe this would give the correct units and equation but is this an acceptable derivation?

Also, as a, sort of, side question why can't I write:

$$\triangle w=\int_Q^0 VdQ$$.

I understand that work is an inexact differential but I fail to understand the argument regarding paths - surely if you change the charge of a particle from one value to another, you must be doing the same amount of work no matter how you do it. This argument must be wrong but I don't know why and why does this mean I cant write $\triangle w$? I know you can do this for things like entropy and enthalpy because they are state functions - I just don't understand the difference. Thanks.

Comment: Although the meaning of the symbols is rather clear in this case, it is generally advisable to include the definitions of all symbols in any question or answer you post. Furthermore, could you include a reference where you got the equation from? Your substitution $Q^2 = -z^2 e^2$ is a little fishy because this would make $Q$ a complex number and this would entail a lot of trouble with the integral for the work as complex integration is not straightforward. But maybe it is just a typo and the minus sign is not part of $Q^2$.

Comment: Sorry, yes it was a typo. I have made amendments.